# Using statements broken after upgrading to IOS 11 Xamarin.IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, ios11

I recently updated Xcode and Visual Studio 2017 for mac to be able to develop for IOS 11. When that happened, almost all of my code from my old project is underlined in red and eve some basic using statements seem to be broken. For example: 
`using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using UIKit;`
All of these are broken and when I try to run, build, or even clean my project, I get the following error:

```
Error: /Users/davidshepard/Projects/NewEPA/NewEPA/NewEPA.csproj: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (NewEPA)
```

Is this a problem with the new version of Visual studio and Xamarin that I am unaware of. I spent about an hour scrolling through Bugzilla and couldn't find any similar issues, so it may just be that I need to configure my old project to work with the new Xamarin?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may try to unload and reload the project. Or clean the bin and obj folder to have a try.

Comment: @Kevin. I tried both of your suggestions to no avail. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after having updated Visual Studio, my project format was automatically set to MSBuild (Visual Studio 2012). This is what was causing the errors. I just had to **Right-Click on my project ->Tools->Convert Solution Format->select MSBuild (Visual Studio 2017)->Export**
Hope this helps anyone who came across a similar issue.